# Finding the sides of Right Triangle when only angles are given

Tags: triangles

I have a question in which a Right angle triangle is given, one of the angle is 50 degree. Since it is a right angle therefor other two angles are 90degrees and 40degrees.

The perpendicular of this triangle is equal to **x**, while the base of the triangle is equal to **y**.

The question is if **x/y** is greater than 1 or not ?

How come I'd know by just using the variable that if the answer would be greater or less than 1 since there is no other sides are given ?

Here is what the Triangle looks like.

[image]

There is no additional data given whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${x\over y}=\tan50^\circ$

We know that $f(x)=\tan x$ is  an increasing function in $(0,{\pi\over2})$

since $50^\circ >{\pi\over4}$

$\therefore \tan{50^\circ}>1$, Hence $({x\over y})>1$

Answer (score 0):

What are the angles in a right, isosceles triangle? What is the ratio between the two cateta? What happens to the angles when you increase one side? What happens to the ratio?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if $\frac{x}{y}$ is greater than $1$, you're essentially asking which is greater, $x$ or $y$. If $x>y$, then $\frac{x}{y}>1$ and if  $x<y$, then $\frac{x}{y}<1$. (We're talking about an actual triangle here, so both $x$ and $y$ are positively greater than $0$).

Now let's look at the special case where both sides are exactly equal, or $x=y$. (This is called an isosceles triangle). What would that mean for the angles?
To change those angles from those values to the ones you found, which side has to grow, $x$ or $y$? What does that mean for $\frac{x}{y}$?